# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in self-referential objects?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I'm having problems with the jvm compiler.

I'm trying to write a factory method for classes. The factory method has an init() block that helps to define behaviour for the new object. While this method compiles for JVM, I encounter a problem when running it:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method type.ProblematicKt.nullable, parameter $this$nullable
```

Apparently, the object isn't yet defined when I attempt to run the problematicInit() block. How do I fix this?

Seems to be a JVM problem. It seems to work for Javascript compilations. My understanding was that getProblematic would be hoisted, but what's inside the scope would be deferred until it's run designed to be run later - after the factory method is completed.

```
interface ProblematicBuilderScope {
  fun problematicInit(getX: () -> ProblematicInterface)
}

fun getProblematic() = X
class Problematic(...): ProblematicInterface

// Factory method with init() block
val X = Problematic.factory(...) {
  problematicInit{ getProblematic() }
} 

fun factory(init: ProblematicBuilderScope.() -> Unit): Problematic {
  val newObject = Problematic(...)
  val scope = ProblematicBuilderScope(newObject)
  scope.init()
  return newObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a cleaner simpler way to achieve the same builder implementation

```
interface ProblematicInterface

class Problematic(): ProblematicInterface


fun buildProblematic(init: Problematic.() -> Unit): Problematic {
    val newObject = Problematic()
    init(newObject)
    return newObject
}

val x = buildProblematic { 
    // this object type inside this clouse is Problematic
}
```